# Avoiding Martian contamination with Earth microbes

Tags: mars, crewed-spaceflight, life, contamination

Unmanned probes can be sterilized, but when humans begin occupying Mars in large quantities, how can contamination of possible Martian microbes with Earth microbes be avoided?